# Why Bash redirects even when there's no command?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html) says that, after performing expansions

> If no command name results, redirections are performed, but do not affect the current shell environment.

Now, what's a use-case for this? What's the point of redirecting if there's nothing to do, and the redirection don't even affect the current shell environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One use-case is to create a file if it doesn’t exist:

```
>> foo
```

It’s also possible to ensure the file is empty:

```
> foo
```

Input redirections can serve as existence tests, but `[ -f foo ]` works just as well:

```
< foo
echo $?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always create files using just redirection:

```
> "$some_file"
```